# How many fields are too many when querying MySQL?

Tags: mysql, field

I have read many times that we have to avoid reading too many fields when querying MySQL (or any database)...just query the fields you need.

However I have a project where a table has 100 fields per record/row.

The thing is that, everytime I query the database, I need ALL of the fields for further calculations, etc after the query is done.

I will eventually have some 200 users, which will be using the same query/table.
At the moment I have done some continuous testing with 3 PC's at once, constantly querying the database, and there is no performance problem at all, all data is queried at a fraction of a second.
Also note the queries are many times the same (all users query the same thing), so query cache is being hit quite a lot..

But I am concerned when all users (+200) at linked and project is in production, I will start having performance problems.

So...the question, **is 100 fields too many to query ?**

Can **SELECT * ...** be used or would **SELECT field1,field2,field3...** etc be faster ?

I don't know how to "simulate" 200 users querying at the same time...any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: "is 100 fields too many to query ?" You've tested it and the answer, in your case, is **no**. "would SELECT field1,field2,field3... etc be faster ?" Both the lookup that `*` implies and parsing all the fields if mentioned separately takes time, but that's nothing compared to the actual query.

Comment: thanks for comments.
I am not sure what you mean about "* implies parsing...". Are you saying it is better to use * (in this case) or is it better to make the query listing each individual field ?

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas can be found [here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php).

If you have 200 users, you will probably not suffer too much, unless they decide to act in concert. However, I'd probably ask if I really need 100 fields, or if the database can be normalised. If that's what you need, that's what you need.

Comment: +1 A table with 100 fields gives off a dubious code smell. :-)

Comment: trust me on this one, I have looked at reducing the number of fields, however it is not possible.

Although not all records use all 100 fields, most use between 50-60, some 75+, and a few the full 100.

I don't have much experience with mysql, but I really have thought about it and don't know how to make it less than 100 fields

Comment: There *could* be a valid reason to use 100 fields, but it's certainly pretty unusual, so I'd be sceptical. Are there any related sets of fields, that are typically either provided together or mostly NULL? If so, breaking them out into their own entity could well be a good idea.

Comment: yes, there are many fields which are NULL, but I don't know when this happens.
Sometimes the record uses 50 fields (rest are NULL), other times the record uses 75 fields, and 25 fields are NULL...it depends.
Could you elaborate on "breaking them out into their own entity" ?

Comment: Well, if some of the columns represent related values, and they were either all `NULL` or all `NOT NULL`, that would imply they had a meaning of their own. As a trivial example if you had `address1`, `address2`, `address3` and `postcode`, those clearly represent part of a single entity, an `address`, which could meaningfully be thrown into a separate table. There'd be a one-to-zero-or-one relation from the users table to the addresses table, so when there was no address you'd only have one `NULL` column in the users table, and no row in the addresses table.

Comment: got your point, bobince
I'll go back to the drawing board and learn a bit more about SQL before proceeding...

Answer (score 0):

I humbly sugget you need to look into Database Normalization. You can divide up that record.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

MySQL specifically.

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html

Also it's considered bad-form to use "select *" in production code. Personally, if I really do need every field, I use it. YMMV.

HTH

Based on your comment that you can't break the record up: study SQL "Joins" and "subqueries". You'll love 'em. :-)

Comment: If you need every field, `SELECT *` is still a problem because next time you add something to the database you have to find all of those places, rather than just adding your new column the places you know it will be used.

Comment: thanks for link and comments.
But if I divide the record into 4 different tables for example, but I need all fields for calculations, I will still have to query all 25 fields on each of the 4 tables in order to have all the data I need, right ?

Comment: @griseldas, see comment about joins and subqueries above. I must point out that I understand pragmatic reality-based constraints. I'm not a "normalization nazi." :-) Nor a code or comment nazi either. Good Luck.